# Does updating the Gradle plugin via Android Studio affect React Native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

I really don't know what's going on, but ever since I updated my Gradle plugin in Android Studio (as a suggested update by Android Studio) I've been having issues with `npx react-native run-android`, or was I never supposed to mess around with the Gradle stuff, leaving that for React Native?

I'm a total noob to React Native framework

Thanks in advance!

PS: This is my first question on StackOverflow, if I went a little bit off the rail, please bear with me.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ar131.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it affects just the android perspective of your react-native app.**Gradle is a build automation tool** . So it's used to make android bundle or apk as you desire.changing the gradle plugin changes the version, and hence impacts.
Given that you changed the plaugin,  and if its crashing you can revert back.
Or suppose some library requires an updated gradle plugin, so you need to update that.
That's it.

UPDATE:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.2.1-all.zip
```

Find this in the gradle-wrapper.properties file. You can change to the versions in their site, like mine has 6.2.1

Feel free for doubts

Comment: Is there some way I could downgrade the build tool version to the previous one?

Comment: @jedBoy have update dthe answer please chek, and if you found it helpful, you can always mark it accepted. would help :)

Comment: How can I stop Gradle 7.0 from interfering?

Comment: downgrade, try mine  gradle-6.2.1-all.zip

Comment: This time I ran `npx react-native init aNewProject`, and everything started but it still shows `
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0. `  my gradle-wrapper.properties is `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.0.1-all.zip`. IDK if I change it to yours, will it stop showing me that `Deprecated Gradle . . .` shit? I'm sorry this issue has left me miserable for days—I wanna get it over with.

Comment: anyways it just a warning, you can proceed with that, even iwth gradle 7, no issues with that. as long as APk builds its fine.